# Retrieving 2 entries from the same table on a joined condition

Tags: sql

I got an SQL problem I cannot seem to solve and would love some help. I created a script to create a database including example population.

The model of the database is as follows:
[image]

What I would like to see returned are the people combinations of those people that have worked at at least 2 companies that are located in the same city. This means the expected output is:

[image]

Eric and Lisa both have worked at 2 companies located in Denver. Ben and Wendy both worked at 2 companies located in Seattle.

This is the code to work with:

```
create database TestDatabase
use TestDatabase

create table Person (
    person_id int not null primary key,
    perons_name varchar(20) not null
);

create table City (
    city_id int not null primary key,
    city_name varchar(20) not null
);

create table Company (
    company_id int not null primary key,
    company_name varchar(20) not null,
    located_in int null
    foreign key(located_in) references City(city_id)
);

create table worked_at (
    person_id int not null,
    company_id int not null,
    foreign key(person_id) references Person(person_id),
    foreign key(company_id) references Company(company_id)
);

insert into City(city_id, city_name) values (1, 'Denver'), (2, 'Colorado'), (3, 'Seattle');

insert into Company(company_id, company_name, located_in) values
    (1, 'Achme', null), (2, 'Local Store', 1), (3, 'The Bizz', 1), (4, 'Drinks', 3), (5, 'Foodie', 3);

insert into Person(person_id, perons_name) values
    (1, 'Eric'), (2, 'Sam'), (3, 'Wendy'), (4, 'Lisa'), (5, 'John');

insert into worked_at(person_id, company_id) values
    (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 1), (3, 2), (5, 1), (3, 4), (3, 5), (2, 4), (2, 5);
```

Hope any of you can help me out with this one as I can't seem to figure it out myself. I've tried retrieving those people that have worked at at least 2 companies located in the same city (which also did not give the expected result for me), and have no clue how to go on from there.

Comment: The tag sql is too general, you might want to include your database

Comment: I don't understand "combinations of people".    Please explain the results.  I do understand a single person who works at multiple companies in the same city but not combinations.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have edited the post with a description of the expected output.

Comment: @JoPapou13 it should run against any database (ansi sql).

Comment: @RuudVerhoef . . . But what if there were 47 people who both worked at two companies in NYC?  The result set doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If the names are the only thing you need, then you could follow this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=da6071eb8caeca325d2217ab89f3ac9b).

The subquery `A` is finding the number of companies a person have worked in the same area and the `HAVING` clause is filtering the data.
After that a `JOIN` is used to bring forth the employees' names.

```
SELECT Person.perons_name, A.located_in
FROM (
SELECT W.person_id, C.located_in, COUNT(C.company_id) AS companies_in_area
FROM worked_at AS W
JOIN Company AS C
ON W.company_id = C.company_id
GROUP BY W.person_id, located_in
HAVING COUNT(C.located_in)>1)A
JOIN Person
ON A.person_id = Person.person_id
```

***Edit to get picture format output***

Please find in this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=4bb0d8c16440189d12f4ce006235148b).
You could give `RANK` on the data based on every location. You could use this `RANK` in a `PIVOT` statement to get the format. The number of columns is dependent on the max number of people worked in a location.

```
with cte AS (
SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY located_in ORDER BY perons_name) AS ur_rank,
Person.perons_name, A.located_in
FROM (
   SELECT W.person_id, C.located_in, COUNT(C.company_id) AS companies_in_area
   FROM worked_at AS W
   JOIN Company AS C
   ON W.company_id = C.company_id
   GROUP BY W.person_id, located_in
   HAVING COUNT(C.located_in)>1)A
JOIN Person
ON A.person_id = Person.person_id)
SELECT located_in, [1], [2]
FROM cte
PIVOT (
MAX(perons_name) FOR ur_rank IN ([1],[2]))A
```

Comment: This is not an answer that gives the expected result (see the image). It actually gives back an empty result.

Comment: @RuudVerhoef . . . The result is not empty when run on the data in the question:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c6ec085b1e38efa23de5e302d984c2f9.

Comment: @GordonLinoff my mistake was running it against an incomplete version of my example. Could you explain how to get it returned in the format requested as well?